# Multiple LIKE statements in SOQL

Tags: soql

I want to get all email addresses which contain @gnail.com, @gmeil.com or @gmai.com from DB.
I have access only to Workbench and Salesforce Inspector and will need to execute the query periodically.

I tried code as in [Multiple LIKE in SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66128/multiple-like-in-soql/66136)

```
 SELECT CreatedDate,PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE Country__c = 'UA' AND Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gnail.com%' OR Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gmeil.com%' OR Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gmai.com%'
```

Error: *unexpected token: OR*

Also I tried a variant:

```
SELECT CreatedDate,PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE Country__c = 'UA' AND PersonEmail LIKE ('%@gnail.com%', '%@gmeil.com%', '%@gmai.com%')
```

gives an error: *Bind variables only allowed in Apex code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the community.

You need to put brackets around your Likes, because I assume you want `a AND (b OR c OR d)`.

`SELECT CreatedDate,PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE Country__c = 'UA' AND (Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gnail.com%' OR Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gmeil.com%' OR Account.PersonEmail LIKE '%@gmai.com%')`. Try this, should produce correct result.

P.S. do you really need `@gmeil.com`?

Comment: You're awesome. Yes, gmeil and other are typos of gmail. I extract and replace them